# How to develop multi-touch applications in ubuntu 16.04 through javafx？

Tags: javafx, ubuntu-16.04, multi-touch, pinchzoom

```
The javafx application：
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.scene.Group;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.input.MouseEvent;
import javafx.scene.input.RotateEvent;
import javafx.scene.input.ScrollEvent;
import javafx.scene.input.SwipeEvent;
import javafx.scene.input.TouchEvent;
import javafx.scene.input.ZoomEvent;
import javafx.scene.shape.Rectangle;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
public class Main extends Application {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Application.launch(args);
  }

  @Override
 public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
    Group root = new Group();
    Scene scene = new Scene(root, 300, 250);

Rectangle rect = new Rectangle();
rect.setWidth(100);
rect.setHeight(100);
root.getChildren().add(rect);
rect.setOnScroll(new EventHandler<ScrollEvent>() {
  @Override
  public void handle(ScrollEvent event) {
    if (!event.isInertia()) {
      rect.setTranslateX(rect.getTranslateX() + event.getDeltaX());
      rect.setTranslateY(rect.getTranslateY() + event.getDeltaY());
    }
    System.out.println("Rectangle: Scroll event" + ", inertia: "
        + event.isInertia() + ", direct: " + event.isDirect());
    event.consume();
  }
});

rect.setOnScrollStarted(new EventHandler<ScrollEvent>() {
  @Override
  public void handle(ScrollEvent event) {
    System.out.println("Rectangle: Scroll started event");
    event.consume();
  }
});

rect.setOnScrollFinished(new EventHandler<ScrollEvent>() {
  @Override
  public void handle(ScrollEvent event) {
    System.out.println("Rectangle: Scroll finished event");
    event.consume();
  }
});

rect.setOnZoom(new EventHandler<ZoomEvent>() {
  @Override
  public void handle(ZoomEvent event) {
    rect.setScaleX(rect.getScaleX() * event.getZoomFactor());
    rect.setScaleY(rect.getScaleY() * event.getZoomFactor());
    System.out.println("Rectangle: Zoom event" + ", inertia: "
        + event.isInertia() + ", direct: " + event.isDirect());

    event.consume();
  }
});

rect.setOnZoomStarted(new EventHandler<ZoomEvent>() {
  @Override
  public void handle(ZoomEvent event) {
    System.out.println("Rectangle: Zoom event started");
    event.consume();
  }
});

rect.setOnZoomFinished(new EventHandler<ZoomEvent>() {
  @Override
  public void handle(ZoomEvent event) {
    System.out.println("Rectangle: Zoom event finished");
    event.consume();
  }
});

rect.setOnRotate(new EventHandler<RotateEvent>() {
  @Override
  public void handle(RotateEvent event) {
    rect.setRotate(rect.getRotate() + event.getAngle());
    System.out.println("Rectangle: Rotate event" + ", inertia: "
        + event.isInertia() + ", direct: " + event.isDirect());
    event.consume();
  }
});

rect.setOnRotationStarted(new EventHandler<RotateEvent>() {
  @Override
  public void handle(RotateEvent event) {
    System.out.println("Rectangle: Rotate event started");
    event.consume();
  }
});

rect.setOnRotationFinished(new EventHandler<RotateEvent>() {
  @Override
  public void handle(RotateEvent event) {
    System.out.println("Rectangle: Rotate event finished");
    event.consume();
  }
});

rect.setOnSwipeRight(new EventHandler<SwipeEvent>() {
  @Override
  public void handle(SwipeEvent event) {
    System.out.println("Rectangle: Swipe right event");
    event.consume();
  }
});

rect.setOnSwipeLeft(new EventHandler<SwipeEvent>() {
  @Override
  public void handle(SwipeEvent event) {
    System.out.println("Rectangle: Swipe left event");
    event.consume();
  }
});

rect.setOnTouchPressed(new EventHandler<TouchEvent>() {
  @Override
  public void handle(TouchEvent event) {
    System.out.println("Rectangle: Touch pressed event");
    event.consume();
  }
});

rect.setOnTouchReleased(new EventHandler<TouchEvent>() {
  @Override
  public void handle(TouchEvent event) {
    System.out.println("Rectangle: Touch released event");
    event.consume();
  }
});

rect.setOnMousePressed(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {
  @Override
  public void handle(MouseEvent event) {
    if (event.isSynthesized()) {
      System.out.println("Ellipse: Mouse pressed event from touch"
          + ", synthesized: " + event.isSynthesized());
    }
    event.consume();
  }
});

rect.setOnMouseReleased(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {
  @Override
  public void handle(MouseEvent event) {
    if (event.isSynthesized()) {
      System.out.println("Ellipse: Mouse released event from touch"
          + ", synthesized: " + event.isSynthesized());
    }
    event.consume();
  }
});

primaryStage.setScene(scene);
primaryStage.show();
  }
}
```

1. I'm trying to implement an JavaFX application which are able to make
   use of touch events and multi-touch gestures. I'm working with a
   capacitive touch screen-eGalax Touch device, with a EETI eGTouch
   driver (eGTouchD version: 2.5).It connected to a Ubuntu 16.04 LTS PC
   via USB  and created multi-touch events (ABS_MT_SLOT,
   ABS_MT_TRACKING_ID, ABS_MT_POSITION_X, ABS_MT_POSITION_Y) which can
   be read from /dev/input/eventX in the terminal. I have tried a lot
   of methods(include MT4j) to realize it but none of them can
   recognize the touch events.

   But under Windows 7, the same code the touch events are recognized, I can swipe, pinch，zoom, etc.
   Now,The zoom in and zoom out events also can realized through mouse scroll event in Ubuntu and Wondows 7.
2. By contrast, I am found that in Windows 7 the java 8 JDK supply a
   jar called java-access-bridge.jar,but in Ubuntu`s JDK it not
   included. Is this the key to the problem?
3. Since I just started to get acquainted with this stuff, I appreciate
   any hint or help.

Comment: Which version of JDKs are you using on both systems?

Comment: Thanks! On Windows 7 the JDK is  jdk-8u121-windows-i586, On Ubuntu the JDK is jdk-8u121-linux-x86. Now, I am found in Winows 7, the Mouse event synthesized with touch event according to analysis the test sample，it can zoom in/out through MouseScoll and two fingers pinch,but in the Ubuntu the sample only respond to mouseEvent.